# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _admin__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.initAdmin) is not a function

Tags: javascript, axios, momentjs, typeerror, yarnpkg

Uncaught TypeError: (0 , *admin__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.initAdmin) is not a function

I am creating app called pizza tracker app which is basically a food ordering system where you can track the orders you have placed and here while creating the admin page i am getting this error
Can anyone explain me this error and try to resolve this error?

```
import axios from 'axios'
import moment from 'moment'

function initAdmin(){
   const orderTableBody = document.querySelector('#orderTableBody')
   let orders = []
   let markup

   axios.get('/admin/orders', {
    headers: {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
}).then(res => {
    orders = res.data
    markup = generateMarkup(orders)
    orderTableBody.innerHTML = markup
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})

function renderItems(items) {
    let parsedItems = Object.values(items)
    return parsedItems.map((menuItem) => {
        return `
            <p>${ menuItem.item.name } - ${ menuItem.qty } pcs </p>
        `
    }).join('')
  }

function generateMarkup(orders) {
    return orders.map(order => {
        return `
            <tr>
            <td class="border px-4 py-2 text-green-900">
                <p>${ order._id }</p>
                <div>${ renderItems(order.items) }</div>
            </td>
            <td class="border px-4 py-2">${ order.customerId.name }</td>
            <td class="border px-4 py-2">${ order.address }</td>
            <td class="border px-4 py-2">
                <div class="inline-block relative w-64">
                    <form action="/admin/order/status" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="${ order._id }">
                        <select name="status" onchange="this.form.submit()"
                            class="block appearance-none w-full bg-white border border-gray-400 hover:border-gray-500 px-4 py-2 pr-8 rounded shadow leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                            <option value="order_placed"
                                ${ order.status === 'order_placed' ? 'selected' : '' }>
                                Placed</option>
                            <option value="confirmed" ${ order.status === 'confirmed' ? 'selected' : '' }>
                                Confirmed</option>
                            <option value="prepared" ${ order.status === 'prepared' ? 'selected' : '' }>
                                Prepared</option>
                            <option value="delivered" ${ order.status === 'delivered' ? 'selected' : '' }>
                                Delivered
                            </option>
                            <option value="completed" ${ order.status === 'completed' ? 'selected' : '' }>
                                Completed
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </form>
                    <div
                        class="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center px-2 text-gray-700">
                        <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                            <path
                                d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="border px-4 py-2">
                ${ moment(order.createdAt).format('hh:mm A') }
            </td>
            <td class="border px-4 py-2">
                ${ order.paymentStatus ? 'paid' : 'Not paid' }
            </td>
        </tr>
    `
    }).join('')
}
}

export default initAdmin
```

Comment: please include the whole error stack trace to identify problem properly

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _admin__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.initAdmin) is not a function
    at app.js:27089
    at app.js:27090
    at app.js:27092

Comment: (0,_admin__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.initAdmin)();

Comment: This is the line at app.js